# Invariance of radiative transfer equation in the absence of absorption and emission

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

The question is asking me to show that the line-of-sight intensity of radiation is invariant when there is no emission or absorption.

Starting with the radiative transfer equation:

$$
\frac{d}{dz}I_{\nu}=-\kappa_{\nu}I_{\nu}+j_{\nu}
$$

I'm assuimg therefore that $\kappa_{\nu},j_{\nu}=0$? i.e., that there is no emission and no absorption? Or should it be 1? Not sure which is correct?

And would it be invariant if $I_{\nu} =$ constant? Which is really simple given $\frac{d}{dz}I_{\nu}=0$  ??

So, my question is how would I show that the line-of-sight velocity is invariant and is what I have thus far, correct?

Comment: Yes, a quantity stays invariant precisely when its derivative is zero; and if the two coefficients are zero, this is what will happen.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Mice Elf. I'm glad I'm right, and thanks for editing the tags (I'm new to the maths stackexchange so tags aren't quite good for me yet!). Thank you. P.S. If you modify your comment into an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: if both the radiation $\kappa_{\nu}$ and absorption $j_{\nu}$ are equal to zero, then the given differential equation becomes simply 
$$\frac{d}{dz}I_{\nu}= 0$$
and we know from calculus that a function with zero derivative is constant. (The precise reason is the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) that relates the change of function on an interval to the value of its derivative there.)